# Microsoft Applications like powerpoint on cloud through Azure and WCF

Tags: wcf, azure, cloud

I am enrolled in masters program and currently I am learning WCF services, their deployment and Microsoft Azure. I am working on an idea which I am hoping I will be able to pull in next 4-5 months. 
I am hoping, if I could publish applications like powerpoint and excel or may be their basic functions on a Cloud via Azure so anyone can use those features without even having those applications on their machines over the web(only available to authorized personnel) .

I want to ask how viable above approach could be because it is still a very young Idea. And, It would be nice if I get some professional arguments and may be counter arguments.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use Citrix. They do this already.